# How to animate individual view in constraint layout using chain?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I wanted to animate view as shown in the image. How to do it?

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSmKa.png)
I have the following code but *how to set the parameter **current**?*
**How Animation works?**
*When the user moves his finger over the list of icons, the height of the current icon, where the user has touched, is set to 400.*

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout);
View child = layout.getChildAt(current);
child.setMinimumHeight(400);
```

where current is of type  int.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't try to change a `View` height, margin or padding if you want to do an animation.

Do a scale animation instead on focus:

```
View child = layout.getChildAt(current);
child.animate().scaleX(2f).scaleY(2f).setDuration(400).start();
```

Scale to normal size on unfocus:

```
View child = layout.getChildAt(current);
child.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(400).start();
```

Comment: Yeah Okay!
But how to set that current parameter?

Comment: Okay, now the problem is you ask too many questions in 1 post. Make it 2 separate questions and it's easier for us to help